# How can i search an arraylist of a class type in java

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I'm trying to make a method searchMachine() which takes a parameter and prints my machine number(the index number in the Array List) that it finds with that parameter(in this case the cost). Here is my code for some reason , it skips the condition always going to not found even when a machine with that cost has been added. Also ive got angle brackets around the TicketMachine in the field , the website wont show it. My first post pretty new to programming.Any advice would be welcome.

```
public class AutomatedTicketOffice
{
  private ArrayList <TicketMachine>  newMachine;

public AutomatedTicketOffice()
{
  newMachine = new ArrayList<TicketMachine>();
}

public void addTicketMachine(int cost)
 {
  TicketMachine machine = new TicketMachine(cost);
  newMachine.add(machine);
  }

public void insertMoney(int machineNumber, int amount)
  { 
   TicketMachine machine = newMachine.get(machineNumber);
   machine.insertMoney(amount);

  }

public void printTicket()
{  
  for (TicketMachine machine : newMachine)
  {
      machine.printTicket();
  }
}

public void listTicketMachines()
{  int counter = 1;
  int noOfTicketMachines= newMachine.size();  
  if (counter < noOfTicketMachines)
   {
    for(TicketMachine machine : newMachine)
    {System.out.println("Machine no " + ": "+ counter);    

     counter++;
    }
  } 
}

public void searchMachine(int cost)
{ int machineIndex= 0;
  boolean found = false;
  while ( machineIndex < newMachine.size() && !found){

      if (newMachine.contains(cost))
      {System.out.println("Machine no " + " : " + machineIndex );   

         found = true;      
    } else {
      machineIndex++;
      System.out.println("There is no such Ticket Machine");
   } 

  }
}
```

}

Comment: You're checking if `newMachine` contains some `int`, but `newMachine` is an `ArrayList<TicketMachine>`. That will never be true.

Comment: @Manu how do i search , do i search for string and change the parameters of newMachine to string then search again or is there another way to do this?

Comment: @LordAnomander is there a way i can search with a for loop or is that impossible?

Comment: @JavaKid Yes, it is possible, it just makes no sense if you want the index of the `TicketMachine`. You could use `newMachine.indexOf(machine)` to get its index though.

Comment: @LordAnomander my constructor has the parameter (int cost) but cost is already assigned to one of my fields so i dont know how to use, this.cost as the int cost is  already being passed unto on of my fields.Should i also post the code of the TicketMachine class?

Comment: BTW, `newMachine` is a terrible name for a list of ticket machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate through the whole `ArrayList` and compare the `TicketMachine`s manually.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newMachine.size(); i++) { 
      // newMachine is a terrible name for a list, just saying
      if (newMachine.get(i).getCost() == cost) {
         System.out.println("Machine no: " + i);
         found = true;
         // break; // depends if you just want to find one or all of them
      }
}
if (!found)
    System.out.println("There is no such Ticket Machine");
```

Of course `TicketMachine` must allow the access to its parameters.

```
public class TicketMachine {
       private int cost;
       // other variables

       // constructor, i.e.,
       public TicketMachine(int cost) {
          this.cost = cost;
       }

       public int getCost() {
          return cost;
       }
}
```

If `cost` is a `public` field, you can access it in the loop via `newMachine.get(i).cost` instead of using the `Getter` access.

Edit: because you asked.

```
for (TicketMachine machine : newMachine) {
    if (machine.getCost() == cost) {
        System.out.println("Machine no: " + newMachine.indexOf(machine));
        found = true;
        // break; // depends if you just want to find one or all of them
    }
}
```

does the same as the loop above.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void searchMachine(int cost) {
    for (int i = 0; i < newMachine.size(); i++) { 
        if (newMachine.get(i).getCost() == cost) {
            System.out.println("Machine number is: " + i);  
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to return the position number, you can do this:

```
public int searchMachine(int cost) {
    for (int i = 0; i < newMachine.size(); i++) { 
        if (newMachine.get(i).getCost() == cost) {
            System.out.println("Machine number is: " + i);  
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to return the boolean (`true` or `false`), you can do this:

```
public boolean searchMachine(int cost) {
    for (int i = 0; i < newMachine.size(); i++) { 
        if (newMachine.get(i).getCost() == cost) {
            System.out.println("Machine number is: " + i);  
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys i did it with a while loop the main point i was missing was the get method of the ArrayList and using one the getPrice method of the TicketMachine class.This compiles and runs so do the others suggested.

```
public void searchMachine(int cost)
{ int index= 0;
  boolean found = false; 
   while ( index < TicketMachine.size()&& !found){

     if (TicketMachine.get(index).getPrice() == cost)
     {System.out.println("Machine no " + " : " + index );   

         found = true;      
    } else 
       {System.out.println("There is no such Ticket Machine");
            index++;
       }
  }

}
```